# Want to retrieve the Modified date for list of file names present inside a file in CMD prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a list of file names present inside a file called `My_text.txt`, may be more than 100. I want to retrieve the Date modified, basically the `DIR` command output for all those file names.

```
My_Text.txt contains
D:\Users\dsa99_p\Desktop\My_Program1.txt
D:\Users\dsa99_p\Desktop\My_Program2.txt
D:\Users\dsa99_p\Desktop\My_Program3.txt
D:\Users\dsa99_p\Desktop\My_Program4.txt

and so on..
```

I want to retrieve the Date modified for all these My_Program1, My_Program2, My_Program3, My_Program4 files. How to do it? Please help.

If it's possible over Powershell then let me know.

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386). You can't read file contents with DOS batch and you don't have access to long file names by default either. And what have you tried?

Comment: With Powershell can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell the file content can be loaded by [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) and file information can be obtained with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1). So this is how it can be done in PowerShell:

```powershell
Get-Content My_text.txt | ForEach-Object { (Get-ChildItem $_).LastWriteTime }
(Get-ChildItem (Get-Content My_text.txt)).LastWriteTime
```

Both commands do the same thing. Shorter form of them:

```powershell
gc My_text.txt |% { (ls $_).LastWriteTime }
(ls (gc My_text.txt)).LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a batch file solution

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("My_Text.txt") DO ECHO FileName:%%G Modified:%%~tG
```

Comment: is it really modified date? [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) just says that it's `Expands %I to the date and time of file.` without indicating which date time is that

Comment: @phuclv, yes the `FOR` command uses the modified date and time.  The `DIR` command also defaults to the modified date and time when you use it with no options.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is possible that one or more of the files may not exist, I would probably structure my code a little differently. I would first check whether each line related to an existing file, and only then get its information.

The first example I'll provide is for PowerShell, whilst it may seem like more text, it will be far more configurable, especially with regards to modifying the layout and content of the results.

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) command line:

```powershell
(Get-Content -Path '.\My_Text.txt') | ForEach-Object { If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf) { Get-Item -LiteralPath $_ | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime, Name } }
```

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) command line:

```
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %G In (".\My_Text.txt") Do @If "%~aG" Lss "d" If "%~aG" GEq "-" Echo %~tG: %~nxG
```

Single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) version:

```batch-file
@(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In (".\My_Text.txt") Do @If "%%~aG" Lss "d" If "%%~aG" GEq "-" Echo %%~tG: %%~nxG)&Pause
```

*In all examples above, I have assumed that `My_Text.txt` is in the current directory, if it isn't please change its currently relative location `.\` as necessary without modifying its quoting.*